# CSS3 transitions time issue

Tags: html, css

Well im working on a small php script and i have an problem with it when using trantions css3 proprety.When i use transition i dont know why it works fine when the user hover the button and it takes 1s to change background but when the user move the mouse out of the button it doesnt take 1s it changes instantaly.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sN2Pn/)

```
.b{
    width:100%;
}
.b:hover{
    background:#fff;
    transition: 1s;
}
<button class="b">HOVER ME</button>
```

Comment: the button has focus, add that in your css.

Comment: There are 2 problems here, the `transition: 1s` should be declared in the `.b` rule (the normal state) not in the `:hover` rule. Secondly, even with the first fix, it still does not work. It's because the default `background` of the button seems to be unable to animate. You have to set an explicit background for your button, in fact it's `background-color` because only IE11 supports background transition. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/sN2Pn/1/

Answer (score 3):

Put the transition on the base state and it will work both ways.

EDIT:  some browsers will require base values to transition to/from. Also, I wouldn't set a transition without defining what I was transitioning.

Also, I tend not to transition shortcut properties. Ideally, this should be transitioning background-color only.

```
.b{
    width:100%;
    transition:background-color 1s;
}
.b:hover{
    background-color:#fff;

}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5KV5/2/) - revised

Comment: Thank you it work well with button but the only other problem is that when i make it on the base for li and when i load the page html it take also 1s to appear with normal style of li

Comment: in which browser you tested this demo? it appears that it does not work in Opera, Chrome, FireFox, only IE11 seems to animate it but the effect is not clear, it's even ugly indeed (maybe because IE11 supports background transition).

Comment: @user3756377 what do you mean by ***it work well***? I can't get it to work. It's just animated 1 way, the other way (after mouse leaving) goes straight to the end background immediately, unless you specified some explicit background for your button (somewhere) in your actual code.

Comment: My example was demo only. Works in Chrome although some browsers will require base values to transition to/from. Also, I wouldn't set a transition without defining **what** I was transitioning. - http://jsfiddle.net/X5KV5/

Comment: Ah yes, in fact I've just tested in Chrome, it just works on Chrome (I thought Opera now is very similar to Chrome, so I just tested on Opera and thought it's the same on Chrome).

Comment: Also, I tend not to transition **shortcut** properties. Ideally, this should be transitioning `background-color` only.

Comment: Remove  transition:background-color 1s; and use transition : 1s; instead

Comment: That would not be correct. `transition:1a` will transition **everything** and that is not what is required.